# Is the total magnetic moment of an object equal to the sum of the magnetic moments of the parts that compose it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

For example, given a spherical shell with charge $Q$ rotating on its axis, can I think of it as the composition of many concentric coils and integrate the infinitesimal magnetic moments $d\vec \mu$ to calculate the total $\vec \mu$? If so, why is that? It seems so simple but I'm having a hard time justifying it.

Comment: Of course you can do that. The magnetic moment determines the $1/r^3$ component of the magnetic field, far away from the object. And you can calculate such fields by breaking the object up and superposing the fields of the pieces. That means the magnetic moment has to add among the pieces as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however i was having a hard time justifying the “perceived” interactions, such as torque experienced when put in an external magnetic field, rather than the “created” ones which, as you said, follow from the superposition principle.

Comment: Well, torque about a given point is additive too, so there's no problem there either.

Comment: But in the example of the sphere, wouldn’t the torque for each coil be calculated with respect to their centre? In the case of a uniform field no net force is acting on the coil, therefore the torque doesn’t change with respect to the point i choose and i can think of all the infinitesimal torques as calculated with respect to the centre of the sphere. In a non uniform field however this doesn’t work, how can you address the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formalise the approach generally. What is unambiguously defined is the current density $j$. By looking at the multipole expansion, the dipole moment is:
$$
m = \frac12\int x\times j d^3x
$$
Technically, it should be the tensor by analogy with electrostatic:
$$
m^{(2)} = \int x\otimes j d^3x
$$
However, due to the conservation of charge $\nabla\cdot j= 0$, $m^{(2)}$ is antisymmetric, so you can identify it as vector with the cross product.

If you're not familiar with dipole expansion, you can also look at the torque generated by a uniform external field $B_0$:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= \int x\times (j\times B_0)d^3x \\
&= \int [(x\cdot B_0)j-(x\cdot j)B_0]d^3x \\
&= \int [(x\cdot B_0)j+\frac12 x^2(\nabla\cdot j)B_0]d^3x \\
&= \int (x\cdot B_0)jd^3x \\
&= -\int (j\cdot B_0)xd^3x \\
&= \frac12\int[(x\cdot B_0)j-(j\cdot B_0)x]d^3x \\
&= \frac12\int (x\times j)\times B_0d^3x \\
&= \left(\frac12\int x\times jd^3x \right)\times B_0
\end{align}
$$
where I integrated by parts and used the antisymmetry of $m^{(2)}$. Alternatively, you can view the the current density as being generated by magnetisation $M$ such that:
$$
j = \nabla \times M
$$
This is possible again thanks to the conservation of charge. You can define the dipole moment as:
$$
m = \int Md^3x
$$
As a first sanity check, $M$ is defined up to a curl free vector field which you can write as the gradient of a scalar $M\to M+\nabla\chi$. You can check that the definition of $m$ does not depend on the choice of the gauge which will only contribute to a vanishing boundary term.

You can also check the equivalence with the previous definition by integrating by parts and assuming that the boundary terms vanishes:
$$
\begin{align}
m &= \frac12\int x\times jd^3x \\
&= \frac12\int x\times (\nabla\times M)d^3x \\
&= \frac12\int [(\nabla\otimes M)\cdot x-x\cdot (\nabla\otimes M)]d^3x \\
&= -\frac12\int [(\nabla\otimes x)\cdot M-(\nabla\cdot x)M]d^3x \\
&= -\frac12\int (M-3M)d^3x \\
&= \int Md^3x
\end{align}
$$

In general, the boundary term can be important when the domain is finite and you have boundary currents. However, the previous formulae are for the entire space, where you usually do not have currents at infinity. Note that the second formula shows why you get the same result no matter the choice of the origin in the first formula. You can prove it directly from the first formula and uses agin the conservation of charge.

In your case, you can therefore assimilate your rotating charged sphere as a uniformly magnetised sphere, and easily calculate the dipole moment from the second formula.

Hope this helps.